# webRTC in mobile Chrome, iOS version less than 14.3

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, google-chrome, webrtc

I am having issues related to mobile Chrome on older iOS versions not exposing getUserMedia. I used [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-camera-pro) to create a custom camera component for a mobile web app. However, the component does not work in Chrome with an iOS version less than 14.3. Any ideas if this is an actual issue and Chrome users with older iOS versions cannot access WebRTC functionality? Are there workarounds aside from `<input type=“image”/>` and directing users to safari? Everything works totally fine in mobile Safari, on older iOS versions as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome on iOS simply did not support getUserMedia prior to 14.3.
You'll need to check for the existence of `navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` before attemping to call it and offer some user experience when it is not there.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I thought, just wanted to sanity check what I had concluded!! Very helpful :)